# Apply different custom UINavigationBar styles for multiple Views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swift5, uinavigationbarappearance

I am currently struggling with defining multiple custom UINavigationBars for different Views in SwiftUI.

I have defined two different appearances in my UINavigationBar extension: a default one and one with a transparent background.

I am calling `UINavigationBar.defaultNavigationBar()` in my entry ContentView().
And when I'm navigating to another view via `NavigationLink { ... }`, I want to apply the different navigation bar appearances based on the logic in `setNavigationBarStyle`

The switch does not work and the UINavigationBar keeps its initial configuration which is defined in `defaultNavigationBar()`

So my question is, is this the right approach and I am missing some configurations? If not, **what is the right approach to style the UINavigationBar differently based on my current view**?

```
import SwiftUI

extension UINavigationBar {
    static let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

    static func defaultNavigationBar() {
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.audi.barBackground)
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.audi.barContent),
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.typeVFNormalBold.rawValue, size: 12)!
        ]
        appearance.shadowColor = UIColor(Color.audi.barTopSeparator)
        appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(UIImage(named: "back-small")!, transitionMaskImage: UIImage(named: "back-small")!)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

    static func transparentNavigationBar() {
        appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()

        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(Color.audi.barContentOverlay),
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.typeVFNormalBold.rawValue, size: 12)!
        ]

        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        appearance.setBackIndicatorImage(UIImage(named: "back-white-small")!, transitionMaskImage: UIImage(named: "back-white-small")!)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

```
func setNavigationBarStyle(scrollY: CGFloat) {
    if scrollY <= 0 {
        UINavigationBar.transparentNavigationBar()

    } else {
        UINavigationBar.defaultNavigationBar()
    }
}
```